# How to configure more than one svninfo object with grunt-svninfo?

Tags: gruntjs

I need to have two svninfo objects of two different svn repositories. The svn information of the app should be stored in the object svninfo_app and the svn information of the elstr repository (external) should be stored in svninfo_elstr:

- information of repo app -> svninfo_app
- information of repo elstr -> svninfo_elstr

My Gruntfile.js

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  grunt.initConfig({
    svninfo: {
      options: {
        output: 'svninfo_app',
        cwd: '.'
      },
      elstr: {
        options: {
          output: 'svninfo_elstr',
          cwd: './public/jslib/elstr/2.0.dev'
        }
      }
    },
    svn_export: {
      dev: {
        options: {
          repository: '<%= svninfo_elstr.url %>',
          output: 'deploy/'
        }
      }
    }
  });
  // https://npmjs.org/package/grunt-svninfo
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-svninfo');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-svn-export');      
  // Default task.
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['svninfo','svn_export']);   
};
```

Returns a warning and aborts:

```
Running "svninfo" task
SVN info fetched (rev: 4)

Running "svn_export:dev" (svn_export) task
Warning: An error occurred while processing a template (Cannot read property 'url' of undefined). Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

The object svninfo_elstr is undefined. Why this? 
How to configure more than one svninfo object with grunt-svninfo?

Answer (score 1):

Now I found a working solution. The following Gruntfile.js

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  grunt.initConfig({
    svninfo: {
      options: {
        output: 'svninfo_app',
        cwd: '.',
        elstrCwd: './public/jslib/elstr/2.0.dev'
      }
    }
  });

  // https://npmjs.org/package/grunt-svninfo
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-svninfo');
  // Default task.
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['svninfo','svninfo:svninfo_elstr:elstrCwd']);
};
```

Returns

```
Running "svninfo" task
SVN info fetched (rev: 5)

Running "svninfo:svninfo_elstr:elstrCwd" (svninfo) task
SVN info fetched (rev: 305)

Done, without errors.
```

It it necessary to register tow tasks:

1. `'svninfo'` -> returns the informations into the object svninfo_app with default options
2. `'svninfo:svninfo_elstr:elstrCwd'` -> returns the information into the object svninfo_elstr with options elstrCwd

Answer (score 0):

Well, there's no property named `svninfo_elstr`, as the error message says. Your Grunt config doesn't have any `svninfo_elstr` properties.

> How to configure more than one svninfo object with grunt-svninfo?

Maybe it would help to update the post with what you're trying to accomplish in more detail? E.g. what would it look like without the `<%= %>` stuff?

Comment: The task svninfo (https://npmjs.org/package/grunt-svninfo) should create a property svninfo_elstr. It does create a property svninfo_app. But I need a second property containing the information of a second svn repository.